# Как подставить значение enum во время компиляции?

Tags: javascript, typescript, импорт, enum

Скачал [файл](https://gist.github.com/scokmen/f813c904ef79022e84ab2409574d1b45), который содержит перечисление кодов протокола HTTP, в котором есть строка

```
export default HttpStatusCode;
```

Вопрос: как мне импортировать перечисление в TS чтобы во время компиляции в JS на месте его использования было только значение? Например в TS использую так:

```
if (this.readyState == xmlhttp.DONE && this.status == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
}
```

а на выходе было бы так:

```
if (this.readyState == xmlhttp.DONE && this.status == "200") {
}
```

А сейчас компилятор пытается создать объект из импортированного HttpStatusCode и обращаться к нему. Но я хотел бы чтобы в результате подставлялось только значение, как на примере выше.
Может стоит не перечисление использовать а что-то другое?

По сути мне нужно просто подставить содержимое файла библиотеки в целевой файл на время компиляции, а содержимое `const enum HttpStatusCode` удалится самостоятельно.

P.S. Решил путём перевода файла библиотеки в [заголовочный файл](https://metanit.com/web/typescript/4.1.php), а `enum` переименовал в `const enum`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums
Т.е. импортировать точно так же, но нужно объявить как `const enum`.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgCSlADgZSgQykQgGEQATOGAbwCgYGB5AaRgF4YAmABm4Bp6DAHIgoAMRCIw5djAAs3OQIC+tWpWAAbfACcqmuLAgAuGEmQAjODoDcagJYAzGAAoI7NhwzY8hYmUoAOhYAShpBGAB6SJgoChBaZSA

Comment: Спасибо. Подставляет значения как надо. Но можно как-нибудь предотвратить компиляцию файла библиотеки? В настройках tsconfig указал только один файл, а скомпилировались два: целевой и файл подключённой библиотеки. Плюс в целевом файле появилась такая строчка 
"Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });" на что ругается браузер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил путём перевода файла библиотеки в заголовочный файл [*.d.ts], а enum переименовал в const enum.